Does Lutheranism believe in the intercession of the saints?
Do Lutherans believe in any type of intercession of the saints? Calvin believed that a general intercession of the saints was possible, but also that one could not ask for intercession from a specific saint.
In this regard, do Lutherans believe in intercession like Catholics, or only in the intercession of living saints/general intercession?
Preferably, I would like answers with sources from the words of Luther or from Lutheran books, but only if possible.
Thank you!

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

My personal understanding is that "those who have fallen asleep" (to use the Scriptural phrasing) are just that; asleep. As in, not presently conscious. Therefore, leaving aside any potential issues of idolatry, praying to them is no more effective than asking an unconscious person to do something for you while they are unconscious. Clearly, such a person can do nothing.
On the subject of official teachings, see The Apology of the Augsburg Confession and The Smalcald Articles. The former is quite lengthy (I didn't read it in entirety) and seems to spend a lot of effort taking a conciliatory tone toward the (Roman Catholic) Church. Nevertheless, it notes that there is no basis for praying to saints. (It also affirms my initial statement: "whence do we know without the testimony of Scripture that the saints perceive the prayers of each one?") The latter is more blunt, describing the practice as "one of the abuses of Antichrist conflicting" which "destroys the knowledge of Christ". Nor, to the best of my knowledge, is there any (significant) historical precedent for such practices within Lutheranism.
That said, "intercession" can also refer to the question whether "sleeping" saints can pray for us, whether as individuals and/or for the church as a whole. On that note, the Lutheran teaching seems to be... "maybe"; the (earlier) Apology states that "so in heaven [the saints] pray for the Church in general", but the Smalcald articles downgrade this prayer to "perhaps" happening. This sounds consistent with your description of Calvin's teaching "that a general intercession of the saints was possible" (emphasis added).
Therefore, if you are asking about "intercession" in the form of praying to saints, the Lutheran stance is that this is, at best, strongly discouraged. If you are asking whether those saints who have "fallen asleep" continue to pray in any capacity, I would surmise that most Lutherans don't specifically believe that they do, but might not oppose the possibility.

There are a few comments where it appears Luther thought the saints were asleep for the most part. However, as I pointed out in my post, there is an exception that he made for himself and a friend. Or, perhaps, he thought one could pray while asleep?

@Jess, as I said, it's not clear that Luther had a firm belief (and/or that his belief remained constant through his entire life) on that point. As far as Scripture... On the one hand, you have Jesus words in Luke 23:43. On the other, you have many references to those who have departed this life being "asleep", plus that Revelation says all will be judged together on "the last day", and that believers won't know that they're saved until that happens... which implies they haven't been consciously hanging out with God before then.

Does Lutheranism believe in the intercession of the saints?
The short answer is yes, but it differs in respect to what Catholicism teaches as the intercession first saints!
The Augsburg Confession rejects invoking the saints to ask for their help, it affirms that "they pray for the Universal Church in general" in life and in heaven.
Even within Lutheranism, there is some variations of this doctrine amongst Lutherans.
Lutheran confessions approve honoring the saints by thanking God for examples of his mercy, by using the saints as examples for strengthening the believers' faith, and by imitating their faith and other virtues. Although the Augsburg Confession rejects invoking the saints to ask for their help, it affirms that "they pray for the Church universal in general" in life and in heaven. The Augsburg Confession emphasizes that Christ is the only Mediator between God and man, and that He is therefore the only One to and through Whom Christians ought to pray.
Though most Lutheran denominations do not follow the Catholic mentality of definition of the intercession of saints, the Evangelical Community Church-Lutheran, a Lutheran denomination with Evangelical Catholic churchmanship affirmed a belief in the intercession of saints.
For more information about this subject matter the following may be of interest to some:

Reply To A Lutheran On The Intercession & Invocation Of Saints


Good link! That some people choose also to ask for prayers from their friends in heaven (via some sort of possible angelic prayer chain, Rev. 5:8), who constitute the communion of saints, is a matter of private piety in Lutheranism. That Moses, Elijah, etc. were not invoked in New Testament times by the disciples in prayer is why Lutherans don't believe it was an encouraged practice back then.

Simply put No.
It seems unprofitable to inquire about Lutherans without simply noting what Luther himself said.  Basically Luther taught that justification, apart from works, was a huge firefly lamp to our feet that would automatically brush away a whole sea of useless superstitions and carnal substitutions to that single great doctrine, the gospel, of which all salvation depends.
Here he says it quite clearly.

But if, in the common consensus with us in which they began, they had
taught and diligently urged the doctrine of justification—that is,
that we are justified neither by the righteousness of the Law nor by
our own righteousness but solely by faith in Christ—then certainly
this one doctrine would gradually, as it had begun to do, have
overthrown the entire papacy with all its brotherhoods, indulgences,
orders, relics, forms of worship, invocation of saints, purgatory,
Masses, vigils, vows, and the endless other abominations of that sort.
But they have neglected the preaching of faith and of Christian
righteousness, and have tried to accomplish this end in another way,
with great damage both to sound doctrine and to the churches. It has
happened to them somewhat as the German proverb about fishing ahead of
the net says, for by trying to catch them with their hands they have
driven away the fish which the net was about to enclose. (Luther’s
Works Vol 26, page 233)

Note: When he says ‘if they’ in the above he means the Papacy.
With reference to what he saw as the invocations of saints specifically on its own, he actually rarely mentions it because it is simply of little interest to him and never encourages it. Here is one of the few places where he doe mention it.

Others before me have attacked the invocation of saints, and this
pleases me. I believe, too, that Christ alone should be invoked as our
Mediator, a truth which is scriptural and certain. Of the invocation
of saints nothing is said in Scripture; therefore it is necessarily
uncertain and not to be believed. (Luther’s Works Vol 37, 370)



They agree in the first place that all the saints and angels in heaven
intercede for us with God. Secondly, that it is both pious and right
to remember the saints and observe festivals on which we pray God to
let the intercession of the saints avail for us. But whether the
saints are to be invoked by us was not agree on. Indeed, they say that
they do not prohibit it, but since Scripture does not teach the
invocation of the saints they themselves do not wish to invoke them,
not only because Scripture does not teach it, but also because it
seems to them to be a dangerous abuse.

The above quote comes from the 1530 minutes of an early meeting (August 16th & 17th) in which the representatives of Rome heard from the representatives who subscribe to the Augsburg Confession in the 16th century. The quote comes from the book, "Confessing One Faith: A Joint Commentary on the Augsburg Confession by Lutheran and Catholic Theologians".
In the "Apology of the Augsburg Confession" (ad art. xxi, sects. 3, 4), it is admitted that the angels pray for us, and the saints, too, "for the Church in general"; but this does not imply that they are to be invoked.
Bengt R. Hoffman, in his “Theology of the Heart” writes about how in the year of his death (1546), Luther wrote the following to a clergyman in Bremen:  

I shall pray for you, and I ask that you pray for me. Just as I have
no doubt that your prayer is effective in my, so I have no doubt that
your prayer is effective in my life, so I have no doubt that my prayer
will be effective for you. If I depart this life ahead of you -
something I desire - than I must pull you after me. If you depart
before me, then you shall pull me after you. For we confess one God
and with all saints we abide in our Savior.

For further research, I recommend Robert W. Bertram's article Mary and the Saints as an Issue in the Lutheran Confessions. It provides some further helpful nuanced perspectives of the Lutheran position. Bertram presented the essay for “in house” discussion among his dialogue partners for Lutherans and Catholics Dialogue VIII during the February 21-24, 1985 session at Marriottsville, MD.
